# Query Posts Creates 404 Error

Tags: query-posts, archives

When I'm on archives pages I am using the code below to query posts.  In my theme options to_count_home calls the number of posts.

WordPress isn't generating the correct number of pages based on posts_per_page.  Instead it is generating pages based on the number of posts per page I have selected in my default WordPress settings.  For example, if I have 10 posts per page in the settings then set posts_per_page in the code as 5, when I go to the second page (which should have 5 posts on it) I get a 404 error.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$per_page = get_option('to_count_home');
query_posts("posts_per_page={$per_page}");
if (have_posts())
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not modifying your query, but nuking it completely. Please see [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage_Note) documentation in Codex on how to correctly re-run query with changed arguments.